# Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113]

Tags: android, adb

By running below command

```
[suiwenfeng@kaggle Downloads]$ ~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb install
```

Got below error message:

> wxwork_android_2.5.8.7620_100001.apk adb: failed to install
>   wxwork_android_2.5.8.7620_100001.apk: Failure
>   [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries,
>   res=-113]

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @suiwenfeng App should contain native libraries that corresponds to device architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, your apk should include `arm64-v8a` ABI for devices. Using Android Studio  **Apk Analyser** by clicking **Build** -> **Analyse Apk** to check if you have this the corresponding native libs for this ABI.

Comment: so i have to launch a arm arch emulator not x86? that`s right?

Comment: can post your apk structure using apk analyser?  what is your device / emulator ABI?

Comment: Be aware that, `arm` emulator is quite laggy. Usually attaching a real device is a better approach.

Comment: i have see armeabi in analysis apk, but not specify v7 or v8. i will try v8 first.